# How to test for sequences that are not string-like using Python 3's standard library

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, interface, abstract-class

For some time, Python has had [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) (proposed orignally in [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/)) that, especially for container types, make it easier to write code that generalizes across custom types. For example,

```
from collections.abc import Sequence, Set

if isinstance(x, Sequence):
    # Handle lists, tuples, or custom objects that behave like lists
elif isinstance(x, Set):
    # Handle anything that behaves like a set
```

One of the ‘gotchas’ that’s tripped me up a few times is that `str`, `bytes`, and `bytearray` are all considered `Sequence`s, in addition to more obviously list-like objects:

```
from collections.abc import ByteString, Sequence

s = 'hello'
b = b'hello'
ba = bytearray(b'hello')
lst = [0, 1, 2]
t = (0, 1, 2)

islistlike = lambda x: isinstance(x, Sequence)

list(map(islistlike, [s, b, ba, lst, t])) # -> [True, True, True, True, True]
```

This certainly makes sense: usually these three types behave just like lists or tuples of characters (or bytes). However, it seems like a pretty common use case to ask, is this object `x` both list-like and not string-like? The fix is straightforward:

```
islistlike = lambda x: isinstance(x, Sequence) and not isinstance(x, (str, ByteString))

list(map(islistlike, [s, b, ba, lst, t])) # -> [False, False, False, True, True]
```

But this seems like it would be a common enough pattern that I wonder if I'm missing something in the standard library.

- Is there any `abc` in Python's standard library such that `islistlike = lambda x: isinstance(x, abc)` will behave like the last example above?
- Is there any design discussion around `Sequence` vs string-like containers somewhere? (I haven't found anything related to this in the standard library documentation or PEP 3119.)

Comment: 1. Not as far as I'm aware. 2. As you note, the *"string-like containers"* *are* sequences, of single-character strings/bytes (`ByteString` inherits `Sequence`, even), so *"vs"* doesn't really make sense. In many cases a string would be considered a perfectly valid argument to a function or method that takes a sequence, so you'll have to be explicit when that is not the case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the comments! I'd argue that "*vs*" could be appropriate, depending on the situation. Often, I'm thinking of strings (bytes, etc) as single atomic data points, and I want to know, am I dealing with a list-like container of string-like items, or am I dealing with a single string-like item. One place this comes up is using a recursive function to flatten a nested dictionary, for example — inside the recursive function you'd like to dispatch on the type of the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the standard library to easily distinguish between `str` and `bytes`-like sequences vs other sequence types.  If this is common in your code-base then you may want to roll your own.